# The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions - Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am creating an application in **Swift**, and I am creating a screen in which to see the list of registered users in the database.

I added a search bar, to search for the user based on their credentials. When I check to see if what is written in the search bar matches the user's credentials, I get this error:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
> time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.

The code is this:

```
struct UserList: View {
    @StateObject var administratorManager = AdministratorManager()
    @State var ricerca = ""
    
    var body: some View {

        List(administratorManager.users) { user in
            
            if user.name.range(of: ricerca) != nil || user.surname.range(of: ricerca) != nil ||
                user.number.range(of: ricerca) != nil || ricerca == "" {
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(user.number).font(.subheadline)
                        Text(user.name).font(.subheadline) 
                        Text(user.surname).font(.subheadline) 
                        Text(user.school).font(.subheadline)
                    }
                    
                    Button("Delete", action: {
                        administratorManager.deleteData(collection: "Users", number: user.number)
                    }).foregroundColor(.red)
                        .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                }
            }
            
        }.navigationBarTitle("User List") 
        .searchable(text: $ricerca, prompt: "Search")
        .onAppear() {
            self.administratorManager.fetchData(collection: "Users") 
        }
    }
}
```

The error appears when I add this line:

```
if user.name.range(of: ricerca) != nil || user.surname.range(of: ricerca) != nil || user.number.range(of: ricerca) != nil || ricerca == ""
```

If instead I write it only in this way it does not give the error:

```
if user.name.range(of: ricerca) != nil || ricerca == ""
```

I know the line is too long, but I need to find a way to make it work. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to user `Model`:

```
var toCheck: [String] {
    return [name, surname, number]//if number is an Int, replace it with String(number) 
}
```

So your if will look something like that:

```
if user.toCheck.contains(where: {$0.range(of: ricerca) != nil}) || ricerca.isEmpty
```

I'm guessing that number is an `Int` & that's what causing the error.